# creating structres based on the users input

Tags: c++, data-structures

i wanted to know if there was a way to create different structures based on the input of the user. FOr example consider this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;
using std::stringstream;
struct rootset {
  double totSize;
  const char *rStrtPtr;
  const char *rEndPtr;

  struct generations {
    double totSize;
    const char *genStrtPtr;
    const char *genEndPtr; 
    int numOfGen;
    string genName;

    struct object {
      double objSize;
      const char *objStrtPtr;
      const char *objEndPtr;
      string id;
      char markBit;
      char objPtr;


      struct freeList {
    double freeSpace;
    int flNumb; 
      };
    };
  } generation;
};

int main()
{

  int gen =0;
  cin >> gen;

  rootset* pRootSet = (rootset*)malloc(1200);

  for( i=0; i<gen; i++) {
    stringstream out;
    out << i;
   string s = out.str();
   string foo = "generation" + s;
   rootset::generations foo;

  }
}
```

Here the user inputs a number. Based on that i wanted to create that many structures. But i am unable to do this. Please help.
I realized that foo is of type string and i cannot use this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably *don't* want to use `malloc` if you can avoid it (and in this case you can -- quite easily at that).

Instead, I'd use `std::vector`, which would give code something like:

```
int gen;
if (cin >> gen) {
    std::vector<rootset> rootsets(gen);
    // code that uses `rootsets` goes here.
}
```

This will allocate a vector (roughly similar to an array) of `gen` different `rootset` objects. You can do that with `malloc` as well, but it's clumsy and difficult by comparison (and if you try to make it exception safe, that goes up to a lot more clumsy and difficult -- to the point that you're nearly re-inventing `std::vector` before you're done).

Comment: ok. The number inside malloc i have specified for now. But that as well the user will specify. Even though do you think it is recommended to use vector?

Comment: @BrownieTuffy: Yes -- unless you have to write code that's also compatible with a C compiler, you almost never want to use `malloc`.

Comment: In this code, i wanted the structure generation to create new structures. Like if the user inputs gen as 3, Then three structures by name generation0, generation1, generation2 need to be created. Is this possible?